# 403 forbidden error PUT request with yiirestfull plugin and Backbone.JS

Tags: rest, backbone.js, yii

I am working with REST in Yii. Therefore I use yiirestful plugin and Backbone.JS. At the moment I am perfectly able to do POST and GET request throughout REST. But when I want to update a record I alway get an 403 forbidden error. I shall explain what i've tried and how:

First of all I am saving my collection in Backbone like this:

```
Backbone.sync('update', this.collection);
```

Now I don't for sure if that's going to work but the fact is that any PUT request get's an 403.

Secondly, because I am working in a module I adjusted the URLmanager rules like this:

```
    'contentManagement/api/<controller:\w+>'=>array('contentManagement/<controller>/restList', 'verb'=>'GET'),

        'api/<controller:\w+>'=>array('<controller>/restList', 'verb'=>'GET'),
        'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>'=>array('<controller>/restView', 'verb'=>'GET'),
        'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>/<var:\w+>'=>array('<controller>/restView', 'verb'=>'GET'),

        array('contentManagement/<controller>/restCreate', 'pattern'=>'contentManagement/api/<controller:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),


        array('<controller>/restUpdate', 'pattern'=>'contentManagement/api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),

        array('<controller>/restUpdate', 'pattern'=>'contentManagement/api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
        array('<controller>/restDelete', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
        array('<controller>/restCreate', 'pattern'=>'contentManagement/api/<controller:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),
        array('<controller>/restCreate', 'pattern'=>'contentManagement/api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),
```

It could be the case that this causes the problem. But I am not very digged in to this rules.. I did the same as i did by the POST request but whatever I try it still gives the 403.

Thirdly i'll provide my request information:

```
PUT http://pimtest.php/Yii/trackstar/contentManagement/api/SidebarWidgetsUsed/

403 Forbidden
        38ms
```

I think a id is needed after this url but when I provide an id in the data that should be enough to let backbone recognize it's about an PUT request / update request.

I have no clue where to look further in my code.. I understand it's a complicated story so any minimal advice is appreciated!

Greetz,

Comment: Are you sure your web server allows HTTP PUT requests?  Sometimes those are dis-allowed by default.

Comment: Will check this out definitely, should explain why it's always an 403

Answer (score 0):

You have two (identical) rules that apply to PUT, and as you say, they require an ID.  Without an ID, none of the rules will match for a PUT request.

Either provide an ID, or modify the rule to not require an id, e.g.:

```
    array('<controller>/restUpdate', 'pattern'=>'contentManagement/api/<controller:\w+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
```

In any case, as you're not using id, I'm not sure why it's in the rule to start?